# Getting collection depending on the second collection condition. in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to achieve the result:

**Get tweets made by user which emails starts with 'a'.**

```
var Tweet = mongoose.model('Tweets', new mongoose.Schema({
      user_id  : String, 
      text     : String, 
      date     : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    })
);
var User = mongoose.model('Users', new mongoose.Schema({
      name    : String, 
      email   : String,
      date    : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    })
);
```

The queries look like:

```
app.get('/mongodb/tweets/users/get', function(req, res, next) {
  var time = process.hrtime();
  User.find({email : /^a/}, { _id:1 }, function(err, users) {
    var dataArr = [];
    for(o in users) { dataArr.push(users[o]._id); }
    Tweet.find({user_id : { $in : dataArr }}, function(err, tweets) {
      var diff = process.hrtime(time);
      res.send({ seconds : diff[0], nanoseconds : diff[1], result: tweets.length});
    });
  });
});
```

I'm aware that I'm doing something wrong because the performance of those queries are kind of bad in comparison to the normal MySQL query.

Tweets : {"seconds":0,"nanoseconds":904058152,"result":4396}

Tweets (MySQL) : {"seconds":0,"nanoseconds":455872373,"result":4368}

I've also tried to use the [populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method but this occurred in even further lost in performance.

Any suggestions how to handle that in order to make it work faster? I'm looking for clean code that won't require me to do workaround (object to array conversion). What would be the solution to this kind of problem with some elegant and most correct approach?

@kevin

Thanks for the index tip, it helped with performance a lot and made it:
{"seconds":0,"nanoseconds":412133579,"result":4396}

Comment: how many records are in your collections? do you have an index on the user_id field?

Comment: There are exactly 10000 users and 1000000 tweets. About the indexes, good catch - 100% faster than before

{"seconds":0,"nanoseconds":412133579,"result":4396}

Comment: that makes it faster than MySQL timing now. Is that the question answered? Or if not, can you add more detail for exactly what you are looking for. Performance is a very broad topic so you will need to detail what level of performance you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, yes - it answers my question but partially. I would love to hear some feedback about my method, I kind of don't like it, it's like doing some unnecessary logic (parse objs as array for a query). I would love to hear other people opinion/critics so I will code better.

Comment: StackOverflow is a question/answer site and generally any questions that are looking for opinions are shut down pretty quickly. I'll post my answer regarding adding the index below - if you are happy to accept the answer then you can go ahead. If you wish to keep the question open, then I would suggest that you add more specific detail to the issue you are having so everyone can respond with specific answers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index to the `user_id` field. This will improve performance on collections with large numbers of records.